# signed int to signed char in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I would like to convert signed int to signed char efficiently in javascript.
I've tried:

```js
function convertByModular(n) {
    return ((((n + 128) % 256) + 256) % 256) - 128;
}

function convertByTypedArray(n) {
    return new Int8Array([n])[0];
}
console.log(convertByModular(-129));
console.log(convertByTypedArray(-129));
```

Is there other efficient ways to convert signed int to signed char? (especially using bit operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a signed integer to a signed char in JavaScript by using the `<<` (left shift) and `>>` (right shift) operators to limit the value of integers. For example, to convert a signed integer `x` to a signed char, you can do the following:

```js
function toSignedChar(x) {
   return (x << 24 >> 24); // 24 bits left shift and then 24 bits right shift
}

// For example
console.log(toSignedChar(300)); // -28
console.log(toSignedChar(-300)); // 28
```

In the above example, `x` is converted to an 8-bit signed integer (signed char) using 24 bits left shift and then 24 bits right shift. This will retain the last 8 bits of `x` and discard the remaining bits, producing a signed integer of equivalent value.